# SSRS switch statement

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssrs

I have a report with a variable number of columns. I can hide columns with the `ismissing` function based on an expression like `Iif(Fields!Site.ismissing, true, false)`. However, the hidden columns still show when it's exported to Excel and the main purpose of this report is to be mailed out monthly via SharePoint.

My thought was to create a multivalue column whose value depends on a switch statement:

```
=Switch(
Fields!State.IsMissing = true, Fields!Region.Value
  , Fields!Site.IsMissing = true, Fields!State.Value
  , Fields!Site.IsMissing = False, Fields!Site.Value)
```

The idea is:

- if the state is missing show the region field
- if the site is missing show the state field
- if the site is present show the site field

It works if I run the report at the maximum drill down, which is to say if I run it for a specific state the sites in the state show. But, if I go up levels in the hierarchy I get `#error` returned. Any help would be appreciated.